# numpy multiply array elements with another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to code a multispectral image.

Every pixel's value is coded in 33 channels.

I have two numpy arrays `image` and `spectral_range`

For example one image has 4 x 4 pixels:

```
image = np.array([[[1,2,4,3],[2,2,2,1],[1,2,3,2],[5,4,3,2]])
```

And for each pixel should be associated the 33 values of the spectral range covered by the image:

```
spectral_range = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,23,99,166,86,54,12,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

How can I simply create a np.array of shape `(width, height, 33)`, where each pixel's 33 values are the 33 values of the array `spectrum` multiplied by the individual values of the array `image`?

The expected result looks like:

```
result = np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,23,99,166,86,54,12,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,46,198,...etc.]]])
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add an extra axis to `image` and then multiply this array with `spectral_range`. The extra axis makes the two arrays broadcastable with each other:

```
>>> result = image[:, :, np.newaxis] * spectral_range
>>> result.shape
(4, 4, 33)
>>> result
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  23,  99, 166,  86,  54,
          12,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
           0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   2,  46, 198, 332, 172, 108,
          24,   2,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
           0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
        ...
```